# Do logarithms preserve asymptotic equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I know that a function $f(x)$ obey's the asymptotic relation:

$$f(x) \sim A(c-x)^\gamma \text{  as $x\to c$}$$

where $\gamma<0$. I want to know whether it follows that:

$$ \ln f(x)\sim\gamma \ln(c-x) \text{  as $x\to c$}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in this case.
Assume $\lim_cf (x)=0$.
$$f (x)\sim g (x) \implies $$
$$f (x)=g (x)(1+\epsilon_1(x)) $$

$$\implies \ln (f (x))=$$
$$\ln (g (x))\Bigl (1+\frac {\ln (1+\epsilon_1(x))}{\ln (g (x))}\Bigr) $$

$$=\ln (g (x))(1+\epsilon_2 (x)) $$
$$\implies \ln (f (x))\sim \ln (g (x)) $$

this is false if $\lim_cf (x)=1$.

counterexample.
$$x^2+1\sim x+1 \;\;(x\to 0) $$
but

$\ln (x^2+1)$ is not equivalent to $\ln (x+1) $.

Comment: I'm not sure you have noticed that $\gamma$ is negative. Could you give more context as to when it is and isn't valid to take $\ln$ of an asymptotic equivalence. Thanks